# How to access the jetsontx2 camera via ssh using opencv

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ssh, nvidia-jetson

I am currently using a windows computer with gitbash to ssh into an nvidia jetson tx2 with an onboard camera:

```
ssh nvidia@'my ip address"
```

Then I am activating the camera on the jetson tx2 with the command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev nvcamerasrc ! nvoverlaysink
```

I have a python script ready to go to view the camera stream:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this script directly on my jetson tx2 python distribution I have installed this script displays the camera feed.

My question is, how can I make this script work on the machine I'm using to ssh into the jetson tx2?

I believe it has to do with the line:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
```

how does the camera get called when I am sshing into the jetson?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to X11 forward the display. Right now it doesn't know what to do with the output since there is no display connected. If you are running on windows you'll need to download [xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/). Run that (just double click the desktop shortcut) and then:

```
ssh -X nvidia@ip_address
```

Keep in mind that X forwarding is bandwidth limited so it might slow down your process, whatever that may end up being.